# Number of shared components in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
deput(data)

structure(list(genome = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B"), gene = c("esaA", "esaB", "esaC", "esaC", "essA", "essB", 
"essC", "esaA")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
genome = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), gene = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I am interested in the number of items which are shared between each genome, e.g here between A and B it is 1. I can do this (very very slowly) in a loop:

```
out=NULL
for(i in guuids){
print(i)
m<-filter(data,genome==i)
g<-unique(m$gene)
for(z in guuids){
print(z)
p<-filter(data,genome==z)
p<-filter(p,gene %in% g)
p<-nrow(p)
out=rbind(out,data.frame(i,z,p))
}
}
```

but this obviously does not scale and there is surely a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correspondence between character columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550599/correspondence-between-character-columns)

Comment: Sort of, except that the dataset I have is so massive that R complains that it does not yet support long vectors

Answer (score 1):

`table` can count them for you:

```
table(df)
      gene
genome esaA esaB esaC essA essB essC
     A    1    1    2    0    0    0
     B    1    0    0    1    1    1

table(df[,c('gene','genome')])
      genome
gene   A B
  esaA 1 1
  esaB 1 0
  esaC 2 0
  essA 0 1
  essB 0 1
  essC 0 1
```

The returned object is a matrix, so you can simply test for which rows/matrices have more than one non-zero entry.

Comment: thanks - sorry I should have been clearer that in fact there are >3000 genomes, whilst this method will allow me to find the number shared by all what I want is the number shared by each pair (this wasn't clear in the example because there were only 2). I'm not sure this will work for that?

Comment: yes it would scale. you can just subset the table, ```tab = table(x[,c('gene','genome')]) ; tab[rowMeans(tab>0)==1,drop=FALSE,] ``` to look at the results

Answer (score 0):

You can do this based on regex:

First you define all `unique` `gene`s in group `A` as an alternation pattern; you do the same for `B`. Then you subset `df` on those rows for which `grepl` finds  the same `gene` matches:

```
gene_A <- paste0("(", paste0(unique(df$gene[df$genome=="A"]), collapse = "|"), ")")
gene_B <- paste0("(", paste0(unique(df$gene[df$genome=="B"]), collapse = "|"), ")")

df[grepl(gene_B, df$gene) == grepl(gene_A, df$gene),]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  genome gene 
  <chr>  <chr>
1 A      esaA 
2 B      esaA
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(genome = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
                                "B"), gene = c("esaA", "esaB", "esaC", "esaC", "essA", "essB", 
                                               "essC", "esaA")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                               ), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
                                                 genome = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                      "collector")), gene = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `intersect` + `unstack`

```
> do.call(intersect, unname(unstack(rev(data))))
[1] "esaA"
```